# Date timezone issue

Tags: java, date, localization, timezone

I have a UI where user can enter date. Now this date is converted to UTC format in my code which is inside an EJB.

My Query is if the browser in IST and my code is deployed in an server which in EST.

Now to convert to UTC from which timezone I need to convert the date from IST or ETC.

My code is like:

User enters a date in DatePicker. The value of DatePicker is assigned to plain Java Date Object.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do IST to UTC

Your user is selecting date assuming it is IST. So in your server code you need to consider the user time zone before creating a Date object which will be in server time zone. Since server is in EST you need to convert it again to UTC before storing.

Most of the servers have time configured at UTC time zone, so only one conversion is all that is needed in that case.

Answer (score 0):

When you get a Date its in the local time zone.

```
private static final DateFormat FULL_RFC822_DATETIME_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);

public static void date2() throws Exception {
    FULL_RFC822_DATETIME_FORMAT.setTimeZone(new SimpleTimeZone(0, "GMT")); //frozen

    Date d = new Date(); // in local time zone
    System.out.println(d);

    System.out.println(FULL_RFC822_DATETIME_FORMAT.format(d) + " GMT");
}
```

I get

```
Fri Dec 07 11:15:58 CET 2012
Fri, 7 Dec 2012 10:15:58 GMT
```

GMT + UTC are the same.